# How to handle OS generated pop up using webdriverio

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I want to upload file by clicking to a website using webdriverio.
When I click anywhere on choose file field, os level popup is opening.
How to select file from OS-Generated popup and click open button to upload file

Please check these screenshots: [image: Upload File]
Please Check OS-Generated popup: [image: OS-Generated popup]

Comment: Hi @AnjaniKumar Did you find ay solution on this?

Comment: Following code worked for me
browser.execute(function () {
               document.querySelector("input[id=' ']").scrollIntoView({block: "start"})
               document.querySelector("input[id=' ']").classList.value='block';
              });

Comment: Check this related tutorial : https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6AdzyjjD5HCjN6f8ZT2Z4AWr03zwBRkl

Answer (score 2):

[uploadFile](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/uploadFile/) - I think that you need this. Check documentation, it should work properly. You don't need to click, but setValue of input.

Comment: I tried this but I am getting this error:
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 400 due to invalid element state: invalid element state

Comment: And I think, setValue() function will not work in this case, The document upload input box interacts with click only

Answer (score 1):

> [Check this Automation bro YouTube playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6AdzyjjD5HCjN6f8ZT2Z4AWr03zwBRkl)

If either if this doesn't work then use autoIT. Let me know if you need help to setup autoIT if above solution doesn't work for you.